# Problema al devolver la String con identado dos espacios y guion

Tags: java

No me da bien el tercer método de la tabla si alguien me puede ayudar. Adjunto el código intentado. Al implementar el tercer método de la tabla me pide agregar guiones por nivel y no me funciona el programa. Si alguien puede ver el error del tercer método.

```java
    public abstract class Element {

    private String id;

    public Element(String id) {
        this.id = id;

    }

    public getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String print(int spaces) {
        String guiones = "  -";
        for(int i = 0, i<= spaces, i++){
            return guiones.add(spaces[i]);
        }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Qué no te sale? Qué error tienes?

Comment: Es solo que no sé hacer public String print(int ){

Comment: es lo que me falta de la tabla

Comment: @Isma, nosotros solucionamos problemas o errores que tengas en **tu código**,  lo que no hacemos es resolver ejercicios enteros y menos si no tienes al menos una prueba o muestra de lo que has intentado. :(

Comment: @Juantro 17, no sabría bien hacer esa parte, pero tengo pensado en un bucle. Tengo pensado esto pero no me da bien, ese apartado la verdad que no sé, pero intento esto
public String print(int spaces) {
 String guiones = "  -";
 for(int i = 0, i<= spaces, i++){
 return guiones.add(spaces[i]);
Ya tienes mi muestra que lo intente :)

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta con el codigo intentado a ver si ven el error.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, si pones un return dentro de un bucle for solo te contaria una iteración y no hasta `i<= spaces`. Segundo lo que te pide es bastante sencillo, solo necesitas añadir   `-` por cada nivel pues con un bucle for añades un    `-` en cada iteración y listo quedandote tal que así:

```
public static String print(int spaces) {
    String guiones = "  -";
    for(int i=1; i<spaces; i++) {
        guiones=guiones+"  -";
    }
    return guiones;
}
```

Y ya despues del for indicas el return.
Estoy suponiendo que el nivel nunca será cero pero como no lo indica no lo he tenido en cuenta.

Comment: @EnriqueMuchas gracias.

Comment: Es correcto, pero no me deja  validarlo correctamente porque tengo menos de 15 de reputacion pone  los que tienen votos emitidos por quienes tienen menos de 15 de reputación se registran, pero no cambian la puntuación que se muestra públicamente

Comment: @Isma tu reputacion no tiene nada que ver con aceptar una respuesta que te dieron... Eso lo podes hacer, sin reputacion...